# Overiding the css of an parent div with child div

Tags: css

I have a parent class "tab content" with width = 960px and a child class "wrap" with width = 980px . Due to this full animation is not visible.
The css for parent and child divs are in separate css files and I only have access to child css file.
How can I override the parent CSS with the child.
I have already tried using !important tag.
The Div structure is something like this:

```
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div id="section_1">
     <div id="presentation_1" class="presentation" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
       <div class="presentationContent">
           <div class="animationContainer">
             <div  class="wrap" ></div>
```

Comment: there is no parent selector in css till date. `!important` doesn't work?

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML markup?

Comment: he's right, theirs no current way to access "parent" selectors through css alone, see here: http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/ ,,, you'll need to use javascript or jQuery to achieve this.. Either that or set your ".wrap" class to 100% and let the animation be dynamic in width.

Comment: CSS styles are global, so you can include your styles inside html markup using style tag or include styles into second css file and override .tab-content width

Comment: Sorry everyone for delayed response, I finally figured out what I was doing wrong, What I was trying is to use the !important tag for the wrap class which was not working so instead I got permission to use the !important tag for the "tab-content" class in my css file. This solved the issue. Sorry I bothered you all.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the `tab-content`, and make a rule in your stylesheet changing the width. As there is no current ID, only a class, your ID rule will precede the original `class` rule in the stylesheet you cannot access.

```
<div class="tab-content" id="slideshowDiv">
```

Then add your CSS rule in your stylesheet

```
#slideshowDiv { width: 960px }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually the problem in my case was that I did't have the access to full html file. I only designed a few animations which was to be included in the clients file. So I got permission form the client to use the !important tag for the "tab-content" class in my css file. This solved the issue.

Comment: Glad you solved it, but you should bear in mind you should try to avoid using !important as much as possible. If you can solve it by using an ID rather than a class, that will work better. The ID will ALWAYS override the class styling.